# "hat arbeitet müssen" or "hat arbeiten müssen"?

Tags: modal-verb, perfect-tense

> He claims that he [had to]/[has had to] work on this book for 3 years.
>
> 1) Er behauptet, dass er an diesem Buch 3 Jahre hat **arbeitet** müssen.
>    2) Er behauptet, dass er an diesem Buch 3 Jahre hat **arbeiten** müssen.

The book I am reading says the verb **haben** must be before the 2 infinitives but gives option 1) as an example, i.e. there're no 2 infinitives there?! And so I am confused.

Comment: @Loong No, it's not a duplicate, I am aware of this rule. So there must be 2 infinitives there and the book has a typo, right? I just want a confirmation that 1) is wrong while 2) is correct.

Comment: I see; well all right then, I retract my close vote.

Comment: @Loong Will you just confirm my guess then ;) ? I assume you're a native speaker.

Comment: Without knowing the context of your book, I tend towards the view that you are right. The sentence No 2 correctly includes two infinitives (_arbeiten_ and _müssen_).

Comment: Version 1) is incorrect.

Comment: @Loong The context of my book: it's just a German grammar.

Comment: OK. Then, yes, it’s probably just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

It was already answered in the comments, but I'll give a detailed answer in case more people stumble across this.

This construction, as I assume you guessed from the English sentence, is a special form of the *Perfekt*. Many modal verbs, especially if they are accompagnied by an infinitive, use this alternative form of the past participle which resembles the infinitive. I disagree with calling it infinitive though, because it's grammatical purpose is that of a past participle, not of an infinitive.

(Minor side note: It also changes the word order, which in a standard perfect tense sentence would have *hat* last.)

The second verb (*arbeiten*) *has to be* an infinitive (because it's an infinitive construction), so it has to end in *n*. Thus, there is a typing error in your book.

Just for completeness, the correct sentences:

> »Ich musste an dem Buch drei Jahre arbeiten.«
>   Er behauptet, dass er an diesem Buch drei Jahre arbeiten musste.
>   »Ich habe an diesem Buch drei Jahre arbeiten müssen.«
>   Er behauptet, dass er an diesem Buch drei Jahre hat arbeiten müssen.

Answer (score -2):

Version 2 is the correct one.

Edit example:

"arbeiten" is the infinitive governed by the verb "müssen" which can't stand alone:

> Er *muss* hart arbeiten.

Transformed to past perfect tense, "arbeiten" is still an infinitive because the finite verb changes, while the structure itself doesn't:

> Er *hat* hart arbeiten *müssen*.

Comment: This answer has been opted to close, but I think it can be easily improved and reviewing it, I don't want to discourage a user who just joined the site. Just keep in mind that answers should be precisely to the point the shorter they are, and should lead to a more general insight into what the question implies, thus helping more people than just the person asking. Please don't post answers as dry one-liners like a quick acclamation while hurrying past, but weigh every word as to give the proper answer to the best of your ability.